# TFS Build - Deployment Folder

Tags: tfsbuild

I have two build servers. On one server, when the unit tests are getting executed, they look for a configuration file in a proper location but in another server, they look for the configuration file the deployment folder.

- Server 1 - Config File Path: D:\Builds\CI\Product\XYZ.config
- Server 2 - Config File Path: D:\Builds\Nightly\tst\Deploy_XYZ 2017-08-22 20_31_20\Out\XYZ.config

There are no differences between the build definitions. I am trying to figure out why one server is looking for the config file in the deployment folder and the other is not.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you may need to review the paths that your test execution steps are searching for tests on. If you don't narrow them down to just the paths where your binaries will be output to then TFS will scan the entire build directory for test adapters, and then scan the entire build directory for tests to run.

This can be less than desirable if your build is producing more than one set of artifacts.